# How to display ordinal number for date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date-format, flatpickr

I am currently implementing flatpickr for my pop-up calendars on my site, and my client has requested to show a specific format for their own use which includes the day of the week, and date with ordinal suffix. As I understand it, I can use a config setting called `altInput` to acheive this, and use `altFormat` to specify exactly how to display it.

Based on this, here is my config and instantiation:

```
var config = {
    enableTime : false,
    dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: 'l, jS F Y'
};

$(".pickr").flatpickr(config);
```

As far as I am concerned, the displayed date should be as follows (using today as the picked date):

> Tuesday, 10th October 2017

However, I actually get:

> Tueaday 1000 October 2017

So it seems the ordinal suffix option (which according to [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is an uppercase S) just displays two zeros. It's almost as if it's treating the uppercase S as a lowercase s, which is for seconds.

Am I missing something here? Is there another way to display the ordinal suffix in javascript?

Comment: `according to PHP.net` - but the code is javascript!!

Comment: as the (one thought out) answer suggests, if you use flatpickr, then refer to flatpickr documentation ... javascript has no date formatting like PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `S` stands for *"Seconds, 2 digits"*

Instead of `jS`, you want `J`:

> *"Day of the month without leading zeros and ordinal suffix"*

Take a look at flatpickr's [formatting documentation.](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/formatting/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Formatting Tokens](https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/formatting/) you should use on altFormat configuration the argument `J` instead of `jS` :

```
var config = {
    enableTime : false,
    dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: 'l, J F Y'
};
```

I've put on the Fiddle for more testing : https://jsfiddle.net/kxssqzu2/14/